# jQuery ui un-hover not always firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

So I've got several things in a list, and when I mouse over them I have a set of buttons that's supposed to show, and hide again when I un-mouse over it. The jQuery I've written to do this, so far, looks like this:

```
    $('li.mine > div').hover(function () {
        $(this).children('span.button-pane').stop().show('clip', 200);
    }, function () {
        $(this).children('span.button-pane').stop().hide('clip', 200);
    });
```

This works great if the user mouses over, and then out entirely. However, if the user mouses directly to another div child of an li.mine, it shows the new buttons and doesn't hide the old buttons. How can I get it so it hides the previous button pane before showing the new button pane?

Edit: Here's some HTMl

```
<li id="list_g236c167c6515484db1a424867cdcb2cb" class="group mine ">
    <div>
        <span class="itemText" data-bind="textToTextbox: Description">Random Group A</span>
        <span class="button-pane align-right" style="float: right; display: block; ">
        <img onclick="JOURNAL.functions.deleteItem(this)" class="float-right hand-cursor delete-button" src="/Content/images/deletered.png" height="18" width="18">    
            <img data-bind="reminderModal: Reminder" class="float-right hand-cursor reminder-button" src="/Content/images/reminder.png">
        </span>
    </div>
    <ol>
        <li id="list_oc647c84fba4c4f5d91f8fdeccb538811" class="no-nest mine ">
            <div>
                <span class="itemText" data-bind="textToTextbox: Description">Random Objective 1</span>
                    <span class="button-pane align-right" style="float: right; ">
                    <img onclick="JOURNAL.functions.deleteItem(this)" class="float-right hand-cursor delete-button" src="/Content/images/deletered.png" height="18" width="18">    
                </span>
                <input type="text" style="display:none" class="itemTextBox">
            </div>
       </li>

       <li id="list_o42c8f0ab4839468b86996f3a3fcff4fa" class="no-nest mine ">
            <div>
                <span class="itemText" data-bind="textToTextbox: Description">Random Objective 2</span>
                <span class="button-pane align-right" style="float: right; display: block; ">
                <img onclick="JOURNAL.functions.deleteItem(this)" class="float-right hand-cursor delete-button" src="/Content/images/deletered.png" height="18" width="18">    
                </span>
                <input type="text" style="display:none" class="itemTextBox">
            </div>
       </li>

    </ol>
</li>
```

Comment: .stop() has no impact on the issue. Also, if I do it slowly, it works. It's just if I quickly move from one li to another.

Comment: Actually, after playing with it some more, it happens with a single li, too. So it's not an issue of them being too close together. If i leave too quickly, it doesn't hide the button pane.

Comment: Maybe it's because you don't close your `<div>`s..?

Comment: Oh, whoops. That's an error in my transcribing the HTML, not in the actual HTML. I cleaned up a lot of knockout stuff that wasn't relevant, and accidentally got rid of the closing div tags.

Comment: Okay, so, the issue is actually because the div doesn't have the button-pane span anymore when it's in the middle of animating. The span gets stuck inside a ui-effects-wrapper. I can get to the span inside of that, and hide/show it, but that just causes the same issues, where it gets put inside a ui-effects-wrapper, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because the span was still being animated. jQuery sticks the pan into another span with the class ui-effects-wrapper while it's animating. So, if it's still animating, we need to catch that fact, and hide it under the ui-effects-wrapper, like so:

```
$('li.mine > div').hover(function () {
        if ($(this).children('.ui-effects-wrapper').length > 0) { // we're still animating!
            $(this).children('.ui-effects-wrapper').children('span.button-pane').show('clip', 200);
        }
        $(this).children('span.button-pane').stop().show('clip', 200);
    }, function () {
        if ($(this).children('.ui-effects-wrapper').length > 0) { // we're still animating!
            $(this).children('.ui-effects-wrapper').children('span.button-pane').hide('clip', 200);
        }
        $(this).children('span.button-pane').stop().hide('clip', 200);
    });
```